# Injecting dependencies to Knockout component via Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js, knockout-components

Is the following snippet a good practice when using Knockout components + Asp.Net MVC? Any drawbacks I am maybe missing?

Is basically injecting part of the ko component dependencies (mainly initial data) by using Razor server side rendering...

Code snippet:

```
<my-component params="{ 
    foo: '@Model.FooProperty',
    bar: '@Model.BarProperty',
    baz: @Json.Encode(@Model.SomeArray)
}"> </my-component>
```

**EDIT:**

For avoiding the string escape issues pointed by @Quango, I've implemented this helper:

```
public static stringEscapeString(this HtmlHelper helper, string value)
{
   return HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(value, true);
}
```

Usage:

```
<my-component params="{ 
        foo: '@Html.EscapeString(Model.FooString)', ...
```

Comment: I'd be cautious about injecting string values without an escape mechanism - e.g. if `Model.FooProperty = "O'Brien"` you'd get a rendering error. Other than that, the only other way would be to use viewModel values which might not be appropriate (if the value does not change)

Comment: @Quango: What do you mean by using viewModel values?

Comment: Knockout can bind values in the `params` section to literal values (as in your example) or to observable values in a Knockout viewmodel if one is present. So the foo passed to the component would be an observable value and the component could then see changes. Examples on my fiddle pages, e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/Quango/tnphvvgd/

Comment: That looks better, yes

Answer (score 0):

We use Knockout in an ASP.NET MVC project at my job, and do consider this bad practise. But the reasons for this might not apply to you. This is something you'll have to judge for yourself

- No caching of HTML (since the injected values might change)
- No bundling of your HTML with your JavaScript (same as above)
- Mixing different solutions for the same problem can be a bad practise, especially in (large) teams. Essentially, you've picked Knockout, so the 'normal' practise would be to acquire any data you need in JavaScript, and bind to it in your view. If this is what you usually do, consider if you really want to create an exception here, just because the data is (supposedly) static. If this is all about saving a few bytes, then just imagine balancing this out to serving ALL your HTML and JavaScript in a minified bundle, that can also be cached on the client.
- No way to override the data later, it is essentially 'hard coded' by the server.
- Your code becomes less portable. Your Razor syntax essentially couples your frontend to your chosen backend technology. If this is a long term project, consider if there might be a small chance that in a couple years from now, you might decide another backend technology might be a better alternative, and if it really makes sense that you'd have to rewrite half the frontend just to make this possible.

None of these reasons are relevant for ALL projects, so it depends a lot on the context. I've tried to list as many possible disadvantages as I could think of.